# FTP client in J2ME

Tags: sockets, java-me, ftp

I am trying to develop a FTP client in J2ME, i have completed the GUI development. But I dont want to re-invent the wheel (if it exists) to write out a full new FTP library. So, Can anyone tell me if there is any FTP library existing for J2ME or not.

Else i have to write the full code using socket programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you trying google?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/j2meftpclient/

It's usually worth trying to find out if there's a library available for your core functionality before you write the front end...

**Update**

It's also worth considering, in the case where you'd have to write your own FTP library, going with another technology if possible. For example, there's HTTP support in J2ME, so if your desired task could be funnelled through HTTP and it would take less time to do that than write an ftp library, consider it.

Comment: i googled the whole lot of things multiple times and check the project fully deeply previously. the project u r referring is incomplete. so, thats the reason i posted the request on stackoverflow. thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Ah ok. It's sometimes worth mentioning if you already googled for it, because so many people don't, and my first thought is "Did they search the web?"

Comment: ohk.so if u have a solution then please suggest.

Comment: i went through ur alternate suggestion. but the thing is, i just want to know whether there is a ftp library or not. else i want to be the one who developed it. FUNNY. but true.

Comment: Ok I see. Afraid I'm can't see any complete looking J2ME FTP libraries out there, given that the one I mentioned already is incomplete.

Comment: thanks for your attempt at solving my problem. i liked your try.