# Render image from ftp server blackberry smartphone client side application

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to display an image from following url using ftp protocol.

```
ftp://64.207.150.31:21/images/gobali.jpg
```

The above url have following pattern when we use in app.

```
ftp://user:password@host:port/path
```

user: remote
password: 123456789

Comment: Is it possible for you to access the server via HTTP, instead of FTP? You can still use authentication with the HTTP server.  BlackBerry Java doesn't have (to my knowledge) a library that implements the FTP protocol, so it would be a lot of work for you to code an FTP client.

Comment: Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381027/ftp-client-in-j2me, http://code.google.com/p/uftplib/.